# how to handle curl session and cookies in php

Tags: php, curl

I want to login via curl and maintain the cookies and session information for further calls.i have created cookie text file in the same directory and used the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR ,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE to maintain the cookie in CUL. whenever i had try to call login api it take the old cookie and show the previous user information. i need to maintain different user cookies and maintain session like normal browser handle. how to do that. any one give idea to do it.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0); // TRUE to include the header in the output.    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // it will follow with server redirects  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);//ssl certificate verifyer
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);  //ssl certificate host

// Set the location of and send the cookies
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookies.txt");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookies.txt");

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );    

$result = curl_exec($ch); //execute curl and store data in result
```

Comment: Do not use a global cookie. Set a different name for each user cookie you want to use.

Comment: if i set separate text file for each user it will occupy memory space in disk?

Comment: yes, of course it will. but unless you're dealing with millions of users, you're unlikely to suck up more than a few megabytes of disk space for the session cookie data.

Comment: how do i create separate cookie for each user? for every login i need to check whether the cookie file is generated or not .

Comment: how to i create multiple cookie for each user ? after login only i can get the response is success before that i couldn't separte the cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify

```
dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookies.txt"
```

Into something like

```
dirname(__FILE__) . '/user_cookies/' . $username . '.txt'
```

You will need to sanitize username for that line so that it will not contain any invalid characters.

Also, set /user_cookies/ permissions to something like 777.

This way you won't need to check if user has cookies or not. If not, the file will be created. If user has them, existing file content will be used.

You could also store cookies in database, but that's way more complicated.